# apt-get update problem in ubuntu 16.4 LTS

Tags: apt, 16.04

I can not `apt-get install` or `apt-get update`

```
W: Failed to fetch http://sd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried everything, but nothing works.
Is it because I live in Sudan? I tried another mirror, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you provide the detailed output of the commands you are trying to run and the output from this

Comment: command : apt-get update

Comment: result after smooth Ign

Comment: configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/partner/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://sd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: when i ping to 8.8.8.8 replay with  100 % packet loss

Comment: If you can't even ping 8.8.8.8, you have a bigger problem than just apt-get. Is your Internet connection being blocked or filtered by your country's government?

Comment: Hmmm ! also may filtrated by my company ! I'll provide a solution of this issue soon as possible

Comment: we resolved this issue by fix issues in firewall of my company ,, thanks all for supporting